# Need SQL code to take a list and associate each value with an alternating even number of states. What is the best way to implement in SQL code?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

This is a SQL Server 2012 SP2 system.

I have a list of values that I can assign to a parameter list but they need to be paired with one of two values in order. I have coded this with a while loop but when the list is odd, my code fails. I have done this in other programming languages with arrays, but SQL doesn't have this function available from my understanding.

Here is the sample list, in which the number of items can be anywhere between 0 and 25 items.

```
declare @value1 varchar(50),@value2 varchar(50),@value3 varchar(50),@value4 varchar(50),@value5 varchar(50), @count int, @numtimes int
set @value1 = 'Sally'  
set @value2 = 'Jenny'
set @value3 = 'Hank'   
set @value4 = 'Jeff'
set @value5 = 'Gina' 
set @value6 = Null
-- I have 25 possible values but if not set, they are null   
set @count  = 0  
set @numtimes =100 -- note that numtimes is a variable in a SP that is set by client application
```

There are only two states possible for the given scenario: 1) Primary and then 2) Secondary.

```
while @count < @numtimes
begin  
    select @count = @count+1

    if @value1 is not null
    insert into table State values (@value1, 'Primary')
    if @value2 is not null
    insert into table State values (@value2, 'Secondary')
    if @value3 is not null
    insert into table State values (@value3, 'Primary')
    if @value4 is not null
    insert into table State values (@value4, 'Secondary')
    if @value5 is not null
    insert into table State values (@value5, 'Primary')
    if @value6 is not null
    insert into table State values (@value6, 'Secondary')
    if @value7 is not null
    insert into table State values (@value7, 'Primary')
    if @value8 is not null
    insert into table State values (@value8, 'Secondary')
    -- my SP does this for 25 values, stopping here to keep art small  

end  -- end of while loop
```

The results from this code are:

Table State

```
╔════════╤═══════════╗  
║ E_id   │ R_ID      ║  
╠════════╪═══════════╣  
║ Sally  │ Primary   ║  
║ Jenny  │ Secondary ║  
║ Hank   │ Primary   ║  
║ Jeff   │ Secondary ║  
║ Gina   │ Primary   ║  
║ Sally  │ Primary   ║  
║ Jenny  │ Secondary ║  
║ Hank   │ Primary   ║  
║ Jeff   │ Secondary ║  
║ Gina   │ Primary   ║ 
║ Sally  │ Primary   ║  
║ Jenny  │ Secondary ║  
║ Hank   │ Primary   ║  
║ Jeff   │ Secondary ║  
║ Gina   │ Primary   ║ 
╚════════╧═══════════╝
```

As you can see in the result set **above**, Gina and Sally are both primary.

**The desired result set is:**

```
╔════════╤═══════════╗  
║ E_id   │ R_ID      ║  
╠════════╪═══════════╣  
║ Sally  │ Primary   ║  
║ Jenny  │ Secondary ║  
║ Hank   │ Primary   ║  
║ Jeff   │ Secondary ║  
║ Gina   │ Primary   ║  
║ Sally  │ Secondary ║  
║ Jenny  │ Primary   ║  
║ Hank   │ Secondary ║  
║ Jeff   │ Primary   ║  
║ Gina   │ Secondary ║ 
║ Sally  │ Primary   ║  
║ Jenny  │ Secondary ║  
║ Hank   │ Primary   ║  
║ Jeff   │ Secondary ║  
║ Gina   │ Primary   ║ 
╚════════╧═══════════╝
```

I have done this in C by using arrays, but I'm confused on how to do this in SQL code.

Comment: SQL is a declarative language. It does not like to do things like looping. Yes it can but it is awkward and horribly slow. Instead of passing a whole list of values maybe you should look into table valued parameters. Then you can send in however many values you want. And if your logic is set based it will be super fast.

Comment: If you really want some help with this you need to explain your business rules. As posted this is incredibly confusing. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider passing 25 values as a single [table-valued parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/bb510489.aspx) instead of 25 separate parameters.
Then it will become a trivial set-based query. And it will work almost `25 * @numtimes` times faster.

Anyway, with your current logic of inserting values one-by-one just keep the count of total inserted rows and determine the 'Primary' or 'Secondary' based on that.

```
DECLARE @RowCount int = 0;

while @count < @numtimes
begin
    select @count = @count+1;

    if @value1 is not null
    begin
        insert into table State values 
            (@value1, CASE WHEN @RowCount % 2 = 0 THEN 'Primary' ELSE 'Secondary' END);
        set @RowCount = @RowCount + 1;
    end;

    if @value2 is not null
    begin
        insert into table State values 
            (@value2, CASE WHEN @RowCount % 2 = 0 THEN 'Primary' ELSE 'Secondary' END);
        set @RowCount = @RowCount + 1;
    end;

    ...
    -- repeat with other 25 variables
    ...

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution. Definitely not the prettiest solution but it will work. Yes SQL doesn't have arrays but you could use a temp table as an array to loop through the values sequentially. The code below performs this by creating a temp table and using a column as an identity value to emulate an array index for each value. This will loop through the possible values and alternate the states as requested in the question above.

```
Create Table #temp  
(RowID int identity(1,1) not null,  value varchar(50))  

declare @number_of_rows int -- rep the total number of values to work with    
declare @counter int        -- represents the increment through the possible values in the loop
declare @number_of_times_2_cylcle_throughList int -- as number of times to cycle through the list  
declare @number_of_repetitions int -- rep the total number times the loop has circled through the list of values    
select @number_of_times_2_cylcle_throughList =10 -- go thru list 10 times
select @number_of_repetitions =0 -- getting ready to start rep 1 
if (    @value1 is not null)  
insert into #temp (EngineerID) values (@value1);  
if (    @value2 is not null)  
insert into #temp (EngineerID) values (@value2);  
if (    @value3 is not null)  
insert into #temp (EngineerID) values (@s_Wk2);  
if (    @value4 is not null)  
insert into #temp (EngineerID) values (@value4);  
if (    @value5 is not null)  
insert into #temp (EngineerID) values (@value5);  
if (    @value6 is not null)  
insert into #temp (EngineerID) values (@value6);  
if (    @value7 is not null)  
insert into #temp (EngineerID) values (@value7);  
if (    @value8 is not null)  
insert into #temp (EngineerID) values (@value8);  

select @number_of_rows = count(*) from #temp -- find the max number of values  
select  @state = 'Primary'  

while @number_of_repetitions  <= @number_of_times_2_cylcle_throughList
begin   
  if (select value from #temp where rowid = @count) is not null  
   insert into table State values ((select value from #temp where rowid = @count), @State)  
  if @state = 'Primary'  
     select @state = 'Secondary'  
  else  
     select @state = 'Primary'  

  select @count = @count+1  
  if @count >@number_of_rows  
 begin  
   select @count =1  
   select   @number_of_repetitions = @number_of_repetitions+1  
 end --end of if
end  -- end of while loop     
Drop table #temp
```